# Question from the book "An introduction to random matrices" about Wishart matrices

Tags: probability, matrices, random-matrices

I found in the book "An introduction to random matrices", an exercise with which I am struggling and have not found an answer for:

> **Exercise 2.4.8:(p.50)** 
>   Let $Y_N$ be a sequence of $N\times M(N)$ matrices with i.i.d entries with zero mean and variance $\frac{1}{N}$ such that $M(N)/N\rightarrow \alpha\in[1,\infty)$, and: 
>   $$ N^{k/2} \mathbb{E}\Big[ \big\vert [Y_N]_{1,1} \big\vert^k \Big] \leq r_k<\infty \quad \text{for all} \quad k,N \in \mathbb{N} $$
>   By writing 
>   $$ W_N=Y_N Y_N^T= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{M(N)} \mathbf{y}_i \mathbf{y}_i \quad \text{for appropriate vectors} $$
>   Show that $\frac{1}{N}\text{tr} \big[ \mathcal{S}_{W_N}(z) \big]$  , where $\mathcal{S}_{W_N}(z)=\big( W_N-zI_N \big)^{-1}$, converges to the solution of the equation:
>   $$ m(z)= \dfrac{-1}{z- \frac{\alpha}{1+m(z)} }$$
>   **Hint:** Use the equality: 
>   $$ I_N+(z-x)\big[ W_N-zI_N \big]^{-1}=(W_N-xI_N)\big[ W_N-zI_N \big]^{-1}  $$
>   and then use the equality: 
>   $$ \mathbf{y}_i^T\big( B_i+\mathbf{y}_i\mathbf{y}_i^T \big)^{-1}= \frac{1}{1+\mathbf{y}_i^T B_i^{-1} \mathbf{y}_i  } \mathbf{y}_i^TB_i^{-1} \quad \text{for} \quad B_i=W_N-zI-\mathbf{y}_i\mathbf{y}_i^T $$
>   to show that the normalized trace of $  \text{tr}\Big( (W_N-xI_N)\big[ W_N-zI_N \big]^{-1} \Big) $ converges to $0$.

**My attempt thus far:**
I think I understand how to solve the problem once I show that the above trace does tend to $0$. If I denote:

$$ \alpha_N(x,z):= \frac{1}{N}\text{tr}\Big( (W_N-xI_N)\big[ W_N-zI_N \big]^{-1} \Big) $$
Then the first equality means that $\alpha_N(x,z)=1+(z-x)\text{tr}\big(S_{W_N}(z)\big)$. The second equality yields that:
$$  \sum\limits_{i=1}^{M(N)} \frac{\mathbf{y}_i^TB_i^{-1}\mathbf{y}_i}{1+\mathbf{y}_i^TB_i^{-1}\mathbf{y}_i} =\text{tr} \big(W_N S_{W_N}(z) \big)=N+z\text{tr}\big(S_{W_N}(z)\big)  $$
Thanks to this I can write:
$$\alpha_N(x,z)= \frac{1}{N} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{M(N)} \frac{\mathbf{y}_i^TB_i^{-1}\mathbf{y}_i}{1+\mathbf{y}_i^TB_i^{-1}\mathbf{y}_i}-\frac{x}{N}\text{tr}\big(S_{W_N}(z) \big) $$
But my attempts to play with this equality to show it does tend to $0$, have all seemed unsuccessful and messy.

So I would like to ask whether someone here encountered this exercise and solved it, or is familiar with the subject matter and suggest a hint how to proceed?

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand your question. I think what you are trying to prove is an expression for the resolvent (the expression involving $m(z)$ which you never define in the body of your question and as such it is unclear what $m(z)$ is) of a covariance matrix of i.i.d Gaussian distributed random variables. Is this what you are looking to do?

Comment: I am trying to prove that $\alpha_N(x_N,z)$ tends to zero in probability, where $x_N \rightarrow \alpha$. Or at least so I think.

Comment: How is $m(z)$ defined?

Comment: It is the function satisfying the equation:
$ m(z)= \dfrac{-1}{z- \frac{\alpha}{1+m(z)} } $

Comment: A relative simple calculation gives us what $m(z)$ is. That is not my problem in the question.

Comment: First of all $W_N$ is a sample covariance matrix in an ensemble where the underlying covariance matrix is equal to identity. Then the   quantity $1/N tr\left[{\mathcal S}_{W_N}(z) \right]$ is the normalized trace of the resolvent and it does not converge to zero when $N \rightarrow \infty$ but it converges to some function of $z$ -- compare https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0305627.pdf for example.

Comment: I am not sure what $ \text{tr}[ {\mathcal S}_{W_N}(z) ]$ since ${\mathcal S}_{W_N}(z) $ is a number and not a matrix. It is the Stieltjes transform of the empirical measure associated with $W_N$. I also do not  seek to show that the normalized trace of what you wrote tends to $0$. In fact ${\mathcal S}_{W_N}(z) = \frac{1}{N}\text{tr} \Big(  (W_N-ZI)^{-1} \big)$.

Comment: So I am not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: I suggest that you read attentively what you wrote in the body of the question marked in yellow.

Comment: I finally read what you commented about clearly, and you are right. I confused myself with a notation in the book, so It did not make sense. I hope it makes sense now.